# A suspicious Isomorphism proof

Tags: idris, theorem-proving, isomorphism

So I have created two representations of integers:

```
data ZZ : Type where
    PZ : Nat -> ZZ
    Zero : ZZ
    NZ : Nat -> ZZ

-- Represent an integer as a difference of two Nats.
data NatNat = NN Nat Nat
```

and two conversion functions:

```
toNatNat : ZZ -> NatNat
toNatNat (PZ k) = NN (S k) Z
toNatNat Zero = NN Z Z
toNatNat (NZ k) = NN Z (S k)

toZZ : NatNat -> ZZ
toZZ (NN pos neg) with (cmp pos neg)
    toZZ (NN (n + S d) n)    | CmpGT d = PZ d
    toZZ (NN z z)            | CmpEQ = Zero
    toZZ (NN p (p + S d))    | CmpLT d = NZ d
```

Please note, that `PZ Z` represents `+1`, and not `0`.

Now I prove that these representations are isomorphic:

```
import Control.Isomorphism

toNatNatToZZId : (z : NatNat) -> toNatNat (toZZ z) = z
toNatNatToZZId (NN k j) with (cmp k j)
    toNatNatToZZId (NN (S d) Z)     | CmpGT d = Refl
    toNatNatToZZId (NN Z Z)         | CmpEQ = Refl
    toNatNatToZZId (NN Z (S d))     | CmpLT d = Refl

toZZToNatNatId : (z : ZZ) -> toZZ (toNatNat z) = z
toZZToNatNatId (PZ k) = Refl
toZZToNatNatId Zero = Refl
toZZToNatNatId (NZ k) = Refl

zzIsoNatNat : Iso ZZ NatNat
zzIsoNatNat = MkIso toNatNat toZZ toNatNatToZZId toZZToNatNatId
```

and to my astonishment Idris politely nods in agreement.

So admittedly this is exactly what I wanted, although I feel a bit uneasy with the fact that I can now prove `NN 0 3 = NN 6 9`:

```
*Data/Verified/Z> the (NN 0 3 = NN 6 9) $ toNatNatToZZId (NN 6 9)
with block in Data.Verified.Z.toNatNatToZZId 6 9 (CmpGT 2) : NN 0 3 = NN 6 9
```

This doesn't seem right. After all, `NN 0 3` *is not* structurally identical to `NN 6 9`. So where exactly Idris got convinced that they're the same? Is this an intended behaviour (I can imagine it is) and if so, how exactly does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof for `toNatNatToZZId` is not total, you only covered some specific cases. If you put `%default total` in the Idris file, the typechecker rejects the definition. Of course, there is no total definition for `toNatNatToZZId`, because as you observed it is not true.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. However, it would be nice to have the compiler consider different values of `NatNat` representing the same integer equal. Is defining custom equality proof-type the only way? It's true that `toZZ` loses *some* information, but none of it is really relevant and it would be nice to have the possibility of communicating this fact to the type-checker.
Also I'm surprised that the proof I constructed in the REPL really worked. From what I know it should have failed due to falling into an unimplmented branch of `toNatNatToZZId`, thus crashing the program…

Comment: @Sventimir you can do what you want here in [cubical Agda](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/cubical.html), but not in Idris.

Comment: That's interesting, thank you. However Agda repels me with its notation involving many non-ASCII symbols, making it hard to read and – I suppose – hard to type. Besides I have just realised that what is really important for me is `toZZToNatNatId` proof, which is correct. The whole isomorphism probably won't be necessary to my purpose. :)